# CSS Grid: `grid-template-areas` — empty area using period not working

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to place elements into a simple 9x9 grid, but when I try to place elements in the bottom-left or -right corners, they are not staying there, and are ending up one box above where they should be. [Here's a JSFiddle showing what I'm trying, and is not working.](https://jsfiddle.net/nr0854qq/2/)

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-area-concept), placing a `.` for empty boxes when defining `grid-template-areas` is sufficient… but I've also tried using normal layout using `grid-area: 1/2/3/4`, and that didn't work either…

This is what I have, css:

```
grid-template-areas: 
"topBar topBar topBar"
". main ."
"aboutDiv . optionsDiv";
```

```css
/* solarized theme colors, trimmed for brevity */
:root {
 --base2:     #eee8d5;
 --base3:     #fdf6e3;
 --yellow:    #b58900;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: var(--base3); 
 height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
   display: grid; 
 grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 0.8fr 0.1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.1fr 0.8fr 0.1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "topBar topBar topBar"
    ". main ."
    "aboutDiv . optionsDiv";
}
.topBar {
 background-color: var(--yellow);
 grid-area: topBar;
}
.main {
 grid-area: main;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
textarea {
 resize: vertical;
 background-color: var(--base2);
}
.aboutDiv {
 grid-area: aboutDiv;
}
.optionsDiv {
 grid-area: optionsDiv;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="topBar">
  
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="titleDiv">
   <p>QARI</p>
  </div>
  <div id="textDiv">
   <textarea id="message" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="buttonDiv">
   <input type="submit" onclick="showMessage(); hideInput()" value="Enter" id="button"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="aboutDiv">
   about
 </div>
 <div id="optionsDiv">
   options
 </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a mismatch between your ID's & Classes

You have ID's in the HTML and classes in the CSS

**HTML**

```
<div id="aboutDiv">
        about
</div>
<div id="optionsDiv">
        options
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.aboutDiv {
    grid-area: aboutDiv;
}
.optionsDiv {
    grid-area: optionsDiv;
}
```

Fix that and it works fine.

```css
/* solarized theme colors, trimmed for brevity */

:root {
  --base2: #eee8d5;
  --base3: #fdf6e3;
  --yellow: #b58900;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: var(--base3);
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.1fr 0.8fr 0.1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.1fr 0.8fr 0.1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "topBar topBar topBar" ". main ." "aboutDiv . optionsDiv";
}

.topBar {
  background-color: var(--yellow);
  grid-area: topBar;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
  background-color: var(--base2);
}

#aboutDiv {
  grid-area: aboutDiv;
}

#optionsDiv {
  grid-area: optionsDiv;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="topBar">

  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="titleDiv">
      <p>QARI</p>
    </div>
    <div id="textDiv">
      <textarea id="message" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="buttonDiv">
      <input type="submit" onclick="showMessage(); hideInput()" value="Enter" id="button" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="aboutDiv">
    about
  </div>
  <div id="optionsDiv">
    options
  </div>
</div>
```